# Stuck in achartengine in android

Tags: android, graph, achartengine

I am developing the android app in which i have used achartengine for creating the graph. Now my concern problem shown in the image below any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apply this to change color

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
```